# App stopped when start an new activity by Intent

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

I'm using Intent to start new activity. I have also add it in my AndroidManifest. But When I click button to call `ContactsActivity.class`, Application get crash.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactsActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Mainactivity.class**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent,SECOND_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);
```

**FATAL EXCEPTION:**

```
2019-01-20 08:04:48.101 30203-30203/com.example.musicplayeronline E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.musicplayeronline, PID: 30203
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.musicplayeronline-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.musicplayeronline-2/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
    at com.example.musicplayeronline.ContactsActivity.<clinit>(ContactsActivity.java:24)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: I think the problem with in the package name com.example.musicplayeronline-2 dosen't follow naming convention try to rename your package right click ->refactor->rename->rename package and the remove -2

Comment: try to invalid cache and restart. if that did not work do clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Please can you check this, hope it help you. https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d

Comment: Thanks evryone. I tried to rename the package and rebuild project. It's worked now.